# Ошибка vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, функции, vector

Вообщем, я занимаюсь по книге Страуструпа и у меня не получается сделать довольно простое задание.

5. Напишите две функции, обращающие порядок следования элементов
   в объекте типа vector. Например, вектор 1 , 3, 5, 7, 9 становится
   вектором 9, 7, 5, 3, 1 . Первая функция, изменяющая порядок следования
   элементов на противоположный, должна создавать новый объект
   класса vector, а исходный объект класса vector должен оставаться
   неизменным . Другая функция должна изменять порядок следования
   элементов в передаваемом ей векторе без использования других векторов.
   Указан11е: воспользуйтесь функцией swap.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//создает новый вектор new vector swap
std::vector<int> nv_swap(std::vector<int>& nv, const std::vector<int> ov)
{
    nv.reserve(ov.size());

    int j = ov.size();

    for (int i : ov)
    {
        nv[j] = i;
        --j;

    }
    return nv;
}

//преобразует старый вектор old vector swap
void ov_swap(std::vector<int>& v)
{

}



int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> ov{ 1 , 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    std::vector<int> nv;
    nv_swap(nv, ov);

    /*std::cout << nv[1];*/
}
```

Comment: `reserve` не изменяет размер вектора

Comment: как я понимаю reserve() меняет количество памяти, которое выделяется под вектор?

Comment: Меняет, однако размер вектора при этом не изменяется. Вы с `resize` путаете. Ну и вообще, в отладчике вы должны были увидеть, что вектор остается пустым.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, раз вы работаете с конкретно `vector<int>`, то...

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void inPlaceReverse(vector<int>& v)
{
    for(size_t i = 0, j = v.size()-1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        int t = v[i]; v[i] = v[j]; v[j] = t;
        // Или короче — swap(v[i],v[j]);
}

vector<int> newReverse(const vector<int>& v)
{
    vector<int> cp(v);
    inPlaceReverse(cp);
    return cp;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<int> src{1,3,5,7,9};
    for(auto i: newReverse(src)) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
    inPlaceReverse(src);
    for(auto i: src) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
}
```

Или нужно с шаблонами/итераторами?

Конечно, можно написать копирование вектора в обратном порядке во второй функции... Но мне кажется, в этом нет никакого смысла: проще скопировать и развернуть скопированный вектор.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я даже не знал что можно так просто копировать значения из одного вектора в другой. И только сейчас заметил идиотизм моей функции nv_swap()

Comment: кстати, что это за переменные описаны в скобках функции main()?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-170